# why does "F" only not work in `qbinom(p=0.025,size=25, prob=0.5, lower.tail = F) `?

Tags: r

I am running this in R:

`qbinom(p=0.025,size=25, prob=0.5, lower.tail = F)`

It gives me `8`

Actually, what I need is really this:
`qbinom(.025, 25, .5, lower.tail = FALSE)`

why does "F" only does not work here?

Comment: You might have assigned some value to `F` earlier. Do `rm(F)` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

`F` is a variable name.  Initially it is set to the *value* `FALSE`, but it can be changed.

For example:

```r
F <- FALSE
qbinom(.025, 25, .5, lower.tail = F)
#> [1] 17
F <- TRUE
qbinom(.025, 25, .5, lower.tail = F)
#> [1] 8
FALSE <- TRUE
#> Error in FALSE <- TRUE: invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You should avoid using `F` to mean `FALSE`.  The savings from less typing are much less than the time wasted when its value changes.  You can't change the value of `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for your help:  I even do not know what my F is ?

Comment: You could try printing it:  just type `F` in the console.

Comment: Thanks.  I got a sequence of numbers for F!

Comment: Variable names like 'M` and 'F` for sex-specific data, or CDF values named `F`, or sequences of variables like `A`, `B`, ..., `F`, ... are pretty common sources of problems like this.